# Docker compose: Cannot start service nginx: Address already in use

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I try to run nginx service in docker-compose, and get this error.
My docker-compose file

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./apps/:/apps
      - ./services/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    depends_on:
      - php73
      - php80
    restart: always
    networks:
      mp-network:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.220.10
...
```

It worked before it... I don't have local nginx or apache2 (port 80 free), and i tried to change port in docker-compose file - result the same.
Help please.

Comment: Seems like something else might be using the ip address.

Comment: i tried to change ip address, without changes ... No more servers up

Comment: if you look at the ipv4 addresses in the network `docker network inspect mp-network | grep IPv4`

Comment: @ChrisDoyle i got - Error: No such network: mp-network

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. The reason was in ipv4_address: 192.168.220.10 - I had 10 services in ipv4_address: 192.168.220.* ips, and 11th was nginx with hard defined ip, wich was busy